# Ruby xls encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4

With [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) I learned export info to Excel with ruby on rails. The problem is data which I pass has wrong encoding and it looks like `_òû _Ü__________`. How can I pass it with right endoding: utf-8 or utf-16?

controller's action:

```
def employees
    start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
    end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])
    @event_members = EventMember.where('created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', start_date, end_date)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xls
    end
end
```

xls.erb template:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ФИО оцениваемого</th>
    <th>Должность текущая</th>
  </tr>
  <% @event_members.each do |event_member| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= event_member.member.full_name %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: [`format.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8).xls`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Encoding.html)

Comment: @mudasobwa `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`

Comment: Sorry, I’m unable to check the code right now, that’s why I just dropped a comment with link to the documentation rather than complete answer. But the solution is to find string and enforce it’s encoding to be `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed simple `meta` tag with `utf-8` encoding

`<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"></meta>`